# Execution fails for task "runExampleClientRPCJava"

Tags: corda

I'm following the CorDapp example tutorial from the main website and am running into problems when trying to run the example RPC client via the command line on Linux

When running the gradle task **./gradlew runExampleClientRPCJava** , I get the following errors.

```
> Task :java-source:runExampleClientRPCJava 
I 13:47:55 1 RPCClient.logElapsedTime - Startup took 7722 msec
Exception in thread "main" ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:787)
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:191)
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:123)
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:86)
        at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:191)
        at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:183)
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:109)
        at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:135)
        at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:120)
        at com.example.client.ExampleClientRPC.main(ExampleClientRPC.java:38)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':java-source:runExampleClientRPCJava'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I can see that it can't connect to any of the servers. Does anyone know why this is and how to solve it? Has anyone run into the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the client is not able to connect to the node in question. This is most likely because the node it is trying to connect to has failed to start.

Try restarting the node and trying to connect again.